# Cost of serving blobstore requests through httpresponse

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

My question is very simple.

What are the costs of serving a blobstore request through an httpresponse.
Right now i'm serving images by uploading them to the blobstore and creating an imageServingLink() and serving the images to the user with that link. This only costs bandwith and not Instance-time but has the limit of 1600 pixels in dimension.

So instead i would like to serve my images through the httpresponse.

So does serving through the httpresponse cost me aditional quota, like instance-time(for the length of the user downloading the image) or only bandwith.

I know i've read somewhere that it only costs bandwith but it's not clear on the blobstore documentation!

And second question:

Is the blobstore httpresponse serving any quicker or slower than serving through the thumbnail service?

Or is there an alternative aproach i can take for serving my images as cheap as possible without giving up to much speed and/or pixels.

I look forward to a response.

**==EDIT==**

This part is not completely clear to me:

> Static content serving (Java, Python) is handled by specialized App
>   Engine       infrastructure, which does not consume Instance Hours. If
>   you need to set custom headers, use the Blobstore API (Java, Python,
>   Go). The actual serving of the Blob response **does not consume Instance
>   Hours.**

So now does the blobstore use an instance or not to serve responses?

What's the difference between a static and dynamic file in the blobstore, and how does the blobstore know?

btw. most of my image uploads will be bigger then 1600 pixels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requests to URLs generated by the Images API do not consume instance hours because they do not require running your application code. The App Engine infrastructure can serve the image to your users without having to ever contact your app, thus no instance time is consumed.

Assuming you're talking about blob serving as documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob) - that is, setting the appropriate blobstore headers and letting the App Engine infrastructure return the blob response - the only additional costs are the instance time consumed by your handler, and the additional latency your users will experience.

Comment: And how much instance time is lost, the full duration of the client downloading the image, or just executing that handler in case of blob serving?

Comment: @Rohan Assuming you mean "used" instead of "lost", the answer is that you only consume instance time while your code is executing - it doesn't matter how long the client takes to download the file.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the answer i was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Images served by `imageServingLink()` / `get_serving_url()` come from dedicated Google hardware specialized in fast image serving, and you pay only for the bandwidth.

If you need to serve the images from your App instead, then of course you will have to pay some instance-time in addition to the bandwidth, and it will be a bit slower. This instance-time is for executing your code up until you return from your request handler, the actual downloading of the data by the client does not consume instance-time.

However if you are just bothered by the 1600 pixels limitation, you can just add a small request handler that serves specifically images 1600 pixels and up, and continue using `imageServingLink()` for the rest. I don't know your use case but usually high-res images are only a small fraction of all images served.

Comment: Could you please look at the question again, i've edited a part.

Comment: I edited my answer. You mean: 'most of my image **downloads** will be bigger then 1600 pixels' ?  In that case, serving the images from your App using the blobstore API seems the only way to go.